# Compute if a natural number is even using single recursion.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic, algorithms, recursion

I know how to compute if a natural number is even by mutual recursion, logically:

```
EVEN_ZERO  -----------------
            (%even 0)  

            (%odd k)
EVEN_SUCC  -----------------
            (%even 1 + k)

            (%even k)
ODD_SUCC   -----------------
            (%odd 1 + k)
```

,which translates into the following functions:

```
(define is-even?
  (lambda (n)
    (if (= n 0)
        #t
        (is-odd? (- n 1)))))

(define is-odd?
  (lambda (n)
    (if (= n 0)
        #f
        (is-even? (- n 1)))))
```

However, I want to compute whether a natural number is odd using single recursion instead of mutual recursion.
This should be possible, but I've trouble figuring out how to do it.

Could someone help me out?

Comment: I've answered your question but I believe that it was more appropriate for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, subtract $2$ instead of $1$ until you either get $0$ (in which case the number is even) or you get $1$ (in which case the number is odd).

```
(define (parity n)
  (cond
    ((= n 0) 'even)
    ((= n 1) 'odd)
    (else (parity (- n 2)))))
```

The above code works correctly only for positive integers, but it is easy to modify it to work with all the integers by working with `(abs n)` instead of `n`.

Notice that the code is tail-recursive, so it runs in constant space.

Comment: Ahh, of course every (positive) integer can be represented as $2k + i$, where $k \ge 0$ and $i = 0 \text{ or } 1$. Thanks.